# dynamiclly count vs database record

Tags: django, django-models

I have a post model as below, now I use `number_of_likes` to record the liked post number. If so, I have to manually maintain the `number_of_likes` field.
Now, I add this field in post mainly two reasons, and I would like to hear your advice.

1. it is easy to write serialisation using declarative syntax(every post need this)
2. I don't need to `filter` and `count` on model `Like`, which is more expensive than just get this value from field

```
class Post(models.Model):
   ...
   number_of_likes = models.IntegerField()

class Like(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   post =  models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to know which method is better, using `Like.objects.filter(user=user).count()` or maintain a new field such as number_of_likes.If choose later, what is the best way to maintain this field

Comment: What would be the purpose of this field ? Will it often change, will it often be seen ?
What's your need of the exact value of this field ? Is it acceptable to update it in an asynchronous task ?

Comment: I think you better annotate the queryset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: @Blusky yeah, it is triggered everytime a new `Like` object is created or deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WillemVanOnsem suggested, best way to display this data is by [`annotation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate). For example:

```
from django.db.models import Count

posts = Post.objects.annotate(num_of_likes=Count('like'))

# usage

for post in posts:
   print(post.num_of_likes)

# or

posts.values('pk', 'num_of_likes')
```